# List of Failed Automations

Tags: marketing-cloud, automationstudio

Is there a way to create a list of f ailed Automations on daily basis and dump those records into any DE? Or any Data view to looks for failed automations?

Comment: You can use ws proxy/SOAP API to retrieve the statuses of automations by performing a retrieve on the object AutomationInstance,

Comment: Never worked on APIs... Any other solution without using APIs...?

Comment: This is only available via API or SDK. And is a significant custom development as you would need not just the automation, but the status of each 'instance' (run) of the automations to get all the failed runs. Otherwise you can talk to SFMC about a service agreement to see if they can create you a custom solution - but be warned it will be expensive.

Comment: The WsProxy together with ssjs will help you, you have to perform a retrieve over AutomationInstance: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_WSProxy_basic_retrieve.htm